# ¿Por qué no muestra nada el método "mostrarDatos()"?

Tags: java

Tengo en Java, en mi código de gestión de una biblioteca, un método llamado *mostrarDatos*, para mostrar los datos de todos los libros que se han introducido, pero por muchos libros que añado siempre muestra "no se han añadido libros" (ese mensaje lo puse dentro de un try-catch).

Clase Biblioteca:

```java
package ejercicio1;

import java.util.Scanner; //importar scanner
public class Biblioteca {

    //número máximo de libros
    private static final int MAX_LIBROS = 10;
    private static Libro [] libros;
    private static int numeroLibros = 0;

    //método principal
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //array con el número máximo de libros
        libros = new Libro[MAX_LIBROS];

        //establecer a 0 el número de libros 
        numeroLibros = 0;
        
        //mostrar el menú
        mostrarMenu();

    }

    //método para el menú
    public static void mostrarMenu(){

        //declaración de variables
        int opcion = 0;

        //activar Scanner
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        //mostrar el menú
        do {

            System.out.println(); //consumir el salto de línea

            //opciones
            System.out.println("------------MENÚ DE LA BIBLIOTECA------------");
            System.out.println("1. Añadir un libro."); 
            System.out.println("2. Buscar un libro por el DNI del autor.");
            System.out.println("3. Mostrar los datos de todos los libros.");
            System.out.println("4. Salir");

            System.out.println(); //consumir el salto de línea

            //pedir la opción al usuario
            System.out.print("Por favor, elige una opción: ");
            opcion = sc.nextInt(); //acordarse de no volver a cerrar el scanner en un método XD

            //switch con las opciones
            switch (opcion) {
                case 1: //opción de añadir el libro
                    anadirLibro();
                    break;

                case 2: //opción de buscar por DNI
                    buscarLibro();
                    break;

                case 3: //opción de mostrar los datos de todos los libros
                    mostrarDatos();
                    break;

                case 4: //opción para cerrar el programa
                    break;
            
                default: //si la opción introducida no es una de las disponibles...
                    System.err.println("ERROR. Opción no válida."); //...mostrar el mensaje de error
                    break;
            }
        } while (opcion != 4);

        //cerrar scanner
        sc.close();
        System.out.println("Saliendo del programa...");

    }

    //método para añadir libros
    public static void anadirLibro(){
        //activar scanner
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        //comprobar que el número de libros no supera el valor máximo
        if (numeroLibros < MAX_LIBROS) {

            //sumar 1 al valor de libros
            numeroLibros++;

            //pedir los datos del libro

                //pedir el isbn
                System.out.print("Por favor, escribe el isbm del libro: ");
                String isbn;

                    //comprobación de que el dormato del ISBN es correcto
                    do {
                        isbn = sc.nextLine();

                            if (isbn.length() != 13) {
                                System.err.print("El ISBN debe tener 13 dígitos. \nPor favor, inténtalo de nuevo: ");
                            }

                    } while (isbn.length() != 13); //seguir pidiendo el dato si el número de caracteres es diferente a 13

                //pedir el año de publicación
                System.out.print("Por favor, escribe el año de publicación del libro: ");
                int anoPublicacion = sc.nextInt();

                    //consumir el salto de línea
                    sc.nextLine();

                //pedir el título
                System.out.print("Por favor, escribe el título del libro: ");
                String titulo = sc.nextLine(); 

            //pedir los datos del autor
                
                //pedir el nombre del autor
                System.out.print("Por favor, escribe el nombre del autor: ");
                String nombreCompleto = sc.nextLine();

                //pedir el DNI del autor
                System.out.print("Por favor, escribe el DNI del autor: ");
                String dni = sc.nextLine();

                //pedir la nacionalidad del autor
                System.out.print("Por favor, escribe la nacionalidad del autor: ");
                String nacionalidad = sc.nextLine();

                Autor autor = new Autor(nombreCompleto, dni, nacionalidad);

            //actualizar los datos
            Libro libro = new Libro(isbn, anoPublicacion, titulo, autor);
            libros [numeroLibros] = libro; //comprobar esta línea

            System.out.println("Libro añadido");

        } else{
            System.err.println("No se pueden añadir más libros.");
        }

    }

    //método para buscar libros por DNI
    public static void buscarLibro(){

        //activar scanner
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Por favor, escribe el DNI del autor: ");
        String dni = sc.nextLine();

            //buscar los libros
            
            for (int i = 0; i < numeroLibros; i++) {
                Autor autor = libros[i].getAutor();
                if (autor.getDni().equals(dni)) {
                    System.out.println("Libro " + (i + 1) + ":"); //mostrar el libro número X
                    System.out.println("ISBN: " + libros[i].getIsbn()); //mostrar el ISBN
                    System.out.println("Título: " + libros[i].getTitulo()); //mostrar el título
                    System.out.println("Año de Publicación: " + libros[i].getAnoPublicacion()); //mostrar el año de publicación
                    System.out.println("Autor: " + libros[i].getAutor().getNombreCompleto()); //mostrar el nombre del autor
                    System.out.println("DNI del Autor: " + libros[i].getAutor().getDni()); //mostrar el dni del autor
                    System.out.println("Nacionalidad del Autor: " + libros[i].getAutor().getNacionalidad()); //mostrar la nacionalidad del autor
                    System.out.println("---------------------------");//consumir el salto de línea
                }
            }

    }

    //método para mostrar los datos
    public static void mostrarDatos(){

        //consumir un salto de línea
        System.out.println();

        //control de errores/excepciones
        try {
            for (int i = 0; i < numeroLibros; i++) { //recuerda que has cambiado el valor de i
                System.out.println("Libro " + (i + 1) + ":"); //mostrar el libro número X
                System.out.println("ISBN: " + libros[i].getIsbn()); //mostrar el ISBN
                System.out.println("Título: " + libros[i].getTitulo()); //mostrar el título
                System.out.println("Año de Publicación: " + libros[i].getAnoPublicacion()); //mostrar el año de publicación
                System.out.println("Autor: " + libros[i].getAutor().getNombreCompleto()); //mostrar el nombre del autor
                System.out.println("DNI del Autor: " + libros[i].getAutor().getDni()); //mostrar el dni del autor
                System.out.println("Nacionalidad del Autor: " + libros[i].getAutor().getNacionalidad()); //mostrar la nacionalidad del autor
                System.out.println("---------------------------");//consumir el salto de línea
            }
        } catch (NullPointerException e) { //excepción que se puede producir si no hay libros
           System.err.println("No hay libros añadidos.");
        }
        
    }
}
```

Clase Libro:

```java
package ejercicio1;

public class Libro {

    //atributos
    private String isbn; /*el "dni" del libro */
    private int anoPublicacion;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
    private String titulo;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
    private Autor autor;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
    //constructor por parámetros                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
    public Libro(String isbn, int anoPublicacion, String titulo, Autor autor){                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
        this.isbn = isbn;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
        this.anoPublicacion = anoPublicacion;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
        this.titulo = titulo;
        this.autor = autor;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
    }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
    //métodos getter y setter

    public String getIsbn() {
        return this.isbn;
    }

    public void setIsbn(String isbn) {
        this.isbn = isbn;
    }

    public int getAnoPublicacion() {
        return this.anoPublicacion;
    }

    public void setAnoPublicacion(int anoPublicacion) {
        this.anoPublicacion = anoPublicacion;
    }

    public String getTitulo() {
        return this.titulo;
    }

    public void setTitulo(String titulo) {
        this.titulo = titulo;
    }

    public Autor getAutor() {
        return this.autor;
    }

    public void setAutor(Autor autor) {
        this.autor = autor;
    }


}
```

Clase Autor:

```java
package ejercicio1;

public class Autor {

    //atributos del autor
    private String nombreCompleto;
    private String dni;
    private String nacionalidad;

    //constructor por parámetros
    public Autor(String nombreCompleto, String dni, String nacionalidad){
        this.nombreCompleto = nombreCompleto;
        this.dni = dni;
        this.nacionalidad = nacionalidad;
    }

    //getters y setters

    public String getNombreCompleto() {
        return this.nombreCompleto;
    }

    public void setNombreCompleto(String nombreCompleto) {
        this.nombreCompleto = nombreCompleto;
    }

    public String getDni() {
        return this.dni;
    }

    public void setDni(String dni) {
        this.dni = dni;
    }

    public String getNacionalidad() {
        return this.nacionalidad;
    }

    public void setNacionalidad(String nacionalidad) {
        this.nacionalidad = nacionalidad;
    }


}
```

Llevo un rato mirando pero no consigo que funcione.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error está aquí :

```
if (numeroLibros < MAX_LIBROS) {
     numeroLibros++; // <-- ERROR
    // resto de código
}
```

Al incrementarse primero el contador provoca que el primer libro se guarde en la posición 1 del arreglo, dejando la posición 0 en `null` y por eso al iterar sobre el arreglo de libros se genera el `NullPointerException`.

Puede corregirse primero insertando el libro y al final incrementado el contador así:

```
if (numeroLibros < MAX_LIBROS){
     // resto de código
     libros[numeroLibros] = libro;
     numeroLibros++;
}
```

Comment: Millones de gracias